# Positioning Text Inside a Triangle CSS

Tags: html, css

So assuming I have the below triangle. Without adding any html or tags how could I go about positioning the text into the center of the triangle?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3LXaD/

You will notice the white text in the top right corner of the triangle. I understand a triangle is a large border around the shape. Is this even possible?

CSS

```
div:nth-of-type(1) {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 150px 130px 150px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #d30000 transparent;
    line-height: 0px;
    _border-color: #000000 #000000 #d30000 #000000;
    _filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
}

div {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>This is a triangle</div>
```

Comment: You can't give a div a zero width and height and render text inside it. Borders are borders and cannot contain text. What would be the use case for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without extra markup try this:

```
div:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 150px 130px 150px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #d30000 transparent;
  line-height: 0px;
  _border-color: #000000 #000000 #d30000 #000000;
  _filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
}

div {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff; 
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 130px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KtVAt/2/).

Ciao
Ralf

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text in the span and position it absolutely:

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/3LXaD/3/)

```
span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 33%;
}

<div><span>This is a triangle</span></div>
```

[Here would be the solution if you were to use a pseuedo element. (not best practice)](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/3LXaD/7/)

```
div:after{
    content: 'This is a triangle';
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 33%;
}
```

Comment: Yes I understand that. But is it possible without adding any tags?

Comment: Why the restriction? It's perfectly normal, even recommended, to use `<span>`s in this kind of situation.

Comment: I get that. Im just asking if its possible. Something I have been playing with and cant seem to get it.

Comment: You could with a psuedo element if you absolutely can't add any HTML. Although this would add markup to the dom. you would just exchange span with div:after

Comment: This is because with a top-border of 0, your text will stack because it doesn't have any width pixels to work with.

Comment: But pseudo-elements should NOT contain actual content. They are for styling purposes only.

Comment: @Paulie_D of course. But within the constraints presented in the question, that would be an acceptable solution.